# Nodejs Callback: How to define a Callback?

Tags: node.js, callback

I am reviewing a sample nodejs server code, which is working fine. but could not understand the following code:

```
   var handlers = {};

   // Creating a sample handler
     handlers.sample = function(data,callback){
     callback(406,{'name':'sample handler'});  // How is this line of code working??
    };

   // Creating a not found handler
     handlers.notFound = function(data,callback){
     callback(404); // How is this line of code working??
     };
```

In the entire code there is no implementation of "callback" function then how

```
       callback(406,{'name':'sample handler'});
```

and

```
       callback(404);
```

are working?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You will likely find what the function stored in `callback` is at the same place `handlers.sample` is invoked elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`callback` isn't implemented in the code you posted; it's a named parameter.

To call one of the functions that requires a `callback`, you'll need to pass it in as an argument, like:

```
handlers.sample("some data", () => console.log("I'm in a callback!));
```

The first argument (`"some data"`) goes in the `data` parameter, and the second argument (`() => console.log("I'm in a callback!)`) goes in the `callback` parameter.  When `callback(404)` is run, it executes the `callback` function (in the above example, it would do `console.log("I'm in a callback!)`).

Comment: Thanks Ollin, This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you call `handlers.sample`, you should pass a function as your second argument, and that function will be called, usually asynchronously, and presumably after something is done with the `data` you pass as the first argument. For example, based on the code you provided:

```
handlers.sample(dataObject, (number, object) => {
  console.log(number)
  console.log(object.name)
})
```

would yield this result in the console:

```
406
sample handler
```

I’m curious if this is a public library you are seeing this code in, so we can take a closer look?

Answer (score 0):

I did a further digging in into this  and found that

```
selectedHandler
```

in the following code (this is not mentioned in the question) is getting resolved into `handlers.sample` or `handlers.notFound` variable names based on some logic (which is not mentioned here)

```
  selectedHandler(data,function(status,payloadData){

    // somelogic with the status and payloadData

  });
```

And second parameter of this function which is a complete function in itself

```
function(status,payloadData){

        // somelogic with the status and payloadData

      }
```

is going as the second parameter in `handlers.sample` or `handlers.notFound` which is a Callback. So execution of Callback in the current context is execution of this function (this function is anonymous because it has no name and getting executed as Callback)